# iOS Interface Builder (XCode): Stick elements together

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, constraints, xcode8

I am having issues with Auto Layout / Constraints in XCode 8.

Here's a screenshot of two of my elements:

[image]

The head is an image while the dotted circle is a button. I need to "stick" the button to this specific position on the image in the background but constraints won't do this for me since they always relate to the bigger layout elements, e.g. View or Top Layout Guide.

Is there any possibility to stick the elements together so the button will aways remain at that specific position (in relation to the image of a person in the background)?

Comment: you could add a transparent view and then center the 2 elements inside it.

Comment: add some view (clear color) with respect to background view and make the button follow this view

Comment: If the head is an image came with background, get background and image separated for best practice

Comment: I've already tried adding a transparent view and nesting the elements inside it. But then I weren't able to tap the buttons. What could I possibly have done wrong?

Comment: just add an UITapGestureRecognizer to your image view, so you don't need that extra UIButton for that function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a gesture for that, without the button

```
@IBOutlet var profileImageView: UIImageView!
```

in viewDidLoad

```
    let tabGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped))
    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tabGesture)
```

and your function

```
func imageTapped() {
    print("image tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the constraint between the control and the image while narrowing the constant delta between them (a negative value will cause them to intersect). Another alternative is to use the CGGraphics functions related to CGRect to force an intersection. Lastly, some combination of these together should be helpful to produce the desired result. Keep in mind that all views on the storyboard have rectangles and can be constrained by both external and interdependent alignments.